# Declare a pointer to structure in const expression

Tags: c, memory-management, static, dynamic-memory-allocation, calloc

I am new to C and can't yet freely navigate trough my program memory. Anyways, I am creating a static memory data type (`gc_menu`) that should hold a pointer to created at execution time structure (`mcl_items`).

For simplicity `mcl_items` structure have one virtual method (`push`) that is going to be run inside of `gc_menu_add_item` and also assigned to the `gc_menu` static space. `push` saves an menu item name (letter) and method to `mcl_item` virtual object.

`mcl_items.h` code:

```c
[...]

typedef struct Items_t {
  int8_t size;
  char names[64];
  void (*methods[64])();
  // Interface
  void (*push)(struct Items_t *self, char c, void (*method)());
}mcl_items;

mcl_items *new_mcl_items();
void mcl_items_push(mcl_items *self, char c, void (*method)());
```

`mcl_items.c` code:

```c
[...]
#include "mcl_items.h"

mcl_items *new_mcl_items() {
  fprintf(stderr, "MCL_Items: Generating a new set of mcl_items..");
  // Build a virtual object
  mcl_items *items    = calloc(1, sizeof(struct Items_t));
  items->push         = mcl_items_push;
  // Set data
  items->size         = 0;
  return items;
}

void mcl_items_push(mcl_items *self, char c, void (*method)()) {
  fprintf(stderr, "MCL_Items: pushing a new item..");
  self->names[self->size] = c;
  self->methods[self->size] = method;
  self->size ++;
}
```

`gc_menu.h` code:

```c
#include "items.h"

typedef struct {
  // Interface
  void (*add_item)(char c, void (*method)());
  // Data
  mcl_items *items;
}__gc_menu;

extern __gc_menu const gc_menu;
```

`gc_menu.c` code:

```c
static void gc_menu_add_item(char c, void (*method)) {
  fprintf(stderr, "GC_Menu: Passing an new item..");
  fprintf(stderr, "length = %i\n", gc_menu.items->size);
  gc_menu.items->push(gc_menu.items, c, method);
}

__gc_menu const gc_menu = {gc_menu_add_item,    // Virtual methods
                           new_mcl_items};      // Data
```

After callng `gc_menu.add_item` the segmentation fault occurs and `gc_menu.items->size` is equal to 72, not 0 as is defined in the definition of `new_mcl_items`.

`main.c` code:

```c
gc_menu.add_item('q', xw->end(xw));
```

```sh
GC_Menu: Passing an new item..length = 72
[1]    66021 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./3D_scean
```

So what am I doing wrong? Why is there such a weird data written to instances of my `gc_menu.items`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've initialized `gc_menu.items` to `new_mcl_items`, i.e. a pointer to the function `new_mcl_items` (which should give you a warning since it is of type `mcl_items *(*)(void)` and not `mcl_items *`).

It looks like what you want is to actually *call* the function `new_mcl_items()` and set `gc_menu.items` to the value that `new_mcl_items()` returns.  You can't do this with an initializer; initializers of global or `static` objects must be known at compile or link time.  Standard C doesn't have "constructors".

So you'll have to remove the `const` from the declaration and definition of `gc_menu`, and add code to `main` (or some function called by `main`, etc) to initialize `gc_menu.items` at run time.

`gc_menu.h`:

```
extern __gc_menu gc_menu;
```

`gc_menu.c`:

```
__gc_menu gc_menu = { 
    gc_menu_add_item,
    NULL // or whatever else you like
};
```

`main.c` or whatever you have called it:

```
int main(void) {
    // ...
    gc_menu.items = new_mcl_items();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Did you forget to remove the `const` from the `gc_menu` declaration inside of the `gc_menu.h`?